# Is constructor a function in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I just came across a data class as follows.

```
class A{
}
```

```
sealed class B
```

```
data class C(val isNext: Boolean = false, val builder: () -> A): A
```

```
class D: A{
}
```

To create an instance of the class, the developer used the following declaration.

```
C{D()}
```

My understanding of lambda, `() -> A` is that its a function without name that takes no arguments and creates an instance of A, however given that A's constructor is called, can I presume that its a function?

Comment: Yes, constructors are functions like any other. Internally, they're special because they, well, construct objects, but to an outside observer they work the same as any other function.

Answer (score 3):

A constructor is a type of function, but you aren't passing it as a function here, because you have wrapped it by calling it in a lambda function. So you have passed a function that internally calls the constructor.

You can pass the constructor directly as a function, like this:

```
val c = C(::D)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tidied up your setup:

```kotlin
open class A
class C(val isNext: Boolean = false, val builder: () -> A) : A()
class D : A()
```

With that in place the following are all equivalent:

```kotlin
    val bldr: () -> A = { D() }

    C { D() }
    // is the same as:
    C(isNext = false, builder = { D() })
    // is the same as:
    C(isNext = false, builder = bldr)
```

So the lambda is just an instance variable named `builder` of `C` just like `isNext` is. **If** it gets invoked in will create a new `D` that happens to be a subclass of `A`